# WordPress TwentyFifteen SubMenu's SubMenu Items to display when using the button associated with the Main Menu Item

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

WordPress Site Using Twenty Fifteen V 1.0

In the Navigation Side-Bar, I have a Main Menu Item with a Sub Menu Item. Like this:

- Main

  - Sub 1

    - Sub Sub 1

When I click the drop-down button associated with the Main Menu Item I get

- Main

  - Sub 1

only.

What I need to happen when I click the drop-down button associated with the Main Menu Item is to get

- Main

  - Sub 1

    - Sub Sub 1

Tried pretty much everything. Got a solution but it makes the button not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you update your question to include the solution you mentioned? Without the code will be really hard to help you.

Comment: .main-navigation ul .current-menu-item ul {
    display: block;
}

I tried adding the above to my CSS file. This leaves the button (that opens and closes the list) to be useless.